# Customize display of event calendar

Tags: trigger, event

I am trying to customize the calendar display. When an event is created, the event currently displays on the calendar like the following:

`subject (location) : Account Name` if the event whatId is related to an Account

or

`subject (location) : Contact Name` if the whodId is related to a Contact

or

`subject (location) : Lead Name` if the whoId is related to a Lead

or

`subject (location) : Opportunity Name` if the event is related to an Opportunity

Is there a way to override the standard display of the calendar event records so I can customize how the event shows up on the calendar? I'm not referring to the hover, but specifically how the event shows up on the calendar. I need to customize the display to be consistent across events where it is related to an account, contact, opportunity or lead...i.e.

`subject (location) : account name - contact/lead or opportunity name` based on what the event is related to.

From what I've found on the idea exchange, there does not appear to be a way to do this. If anyone knows of a way to customize the calendar layout from the standard default of `subject (location) : record name` please let me know.

Comment: what is difference between the standard behavior and the way you want it displayed?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to always show the related account even if the whoId is populated when the whatId is an account or opportunity. When both the whatId and whoId are populated, the calendar layout only displays the name of the contact (whoId) and doesn't include the account name. Same thing for opportunity. I'd like to include the account name with the opportunity name and if the whoId is populated, include the contact name.